# Spring @autowired returning nulls

Tags: java, spring, autowired

This specific class's member private fields which are annotated @autowired are within a service JAR, and when I am trying to get an instance of the class within my code, the @autowired member is always coming back as null. I have the below component-scan statements within my project's context.xml,  which is trying to lookup the base-package within the JAR, but still it appears nulls are being injected into the annotated members. The JAR internally also has a context.xml which has the same component-scan entries as below. The JAR source code cannot be changed now, is there anything I am missing?

```
<!-- local WEB-INF/spring-context/spring-application-context.xml -->
<context:annotation-config /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="blah.blah" />
```

---

```
//this code within my project
//wjc.getMethod() dereferencing comes back null
 public class A{
    WithinJARInterface wjc = new WithinJARInterfaceImpl()
    List someObject = wjc.getMethod()
 }
```

---

```
 //this code interface within JAR
 public interface WithinJARInterface{
    public List getMethod() throws Exception(); 
 }
```

---

```
 //this code within JAR
 public class WithinJARInterfaceImpl implements WithinJARInterface{

    //below member always comes back NULL
    @Autowired
    private JARService jService;

    public List getMethod(){.....}

 }
```

---

```
 public interface JARService{
    public List method1();
 }
```

---

```
  @Service("JARService") 
   public class JARServiceImpl implments JARService {
     public List method1(){ }
  }
```

Comment: How do you obtain your object that has `null` fields annotated with `@Autowired`? Show the code.

Comment: Maybe it is only a typo in the question, but the annotation is `@Autowired` (uppercase A). -- If this is not a typo in the question, then its likely to be the root of your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are constructing the WithinJARInterfaceImpl yourself (by calling `new`)so it isn't managed by spring so the values won't be injected.

Comment: The spring managed bean fixed it. Thx! I should have posted the question sooner

Answer (score 0):

Did you try replacing @Autowired by @Resource? I think @Autowired wires by type while @Resource injects by bean name.